# Does any browser allow me to step through network requests one-by-one?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, frontend

I'm hoping to find which of my page's many network requests are triggering a problem. (Or rather, I want to guide someone else through this process remotely.)

Is there any browser that offers a way to "step through" network requests in the dev tools, pausing the loading of other resources for an arbitrary period before I tell it to step on to the next request?

This is a common feature in IDE environments, but I'm not sure if I've ever heard of it in the browser. (I also tried googling a few phrases without success.) But I'm not a frontender, so maybe it's common knowledge.

Comment: I don't believe you when you say this is a common feature in IDE environments. I've never seen one. What is a common feature in IDE environments is the ability to step through the code (or just skip from one breakpoint to another). This is supported in the dev tools. Just add breakpoints where you do network requests and where you're waiting for the completion of network requests (callbacks, the line of code after an `await`, the `.then()` callback etc.)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I could have been clearer. What I meant was that most IDEs have the ability to step through lines of code, not through network requests. As far as adding `await` or `.then()`, I agree that these could be useful. In the context of the question, I was hoping there was something that I could guide a non-developer in doing in order to isolate the source of a problem he was seeing, the better to maybe fix an API endpoint or something. In any case, thank you for your comment.

Comment: I wasn't saying adding `await` or `.then()` -- I just assumed your code was using them or a callback (otherwise you're writing javascript wrong). I was saying add a breakpoint at the `await`, `.then()` or the callback to the network request. Your browser has the ability to step through lines of code just like the IDEs you mention. And just like the IDEs you mention you can add breakpoints to stop the execution at a specific line of code. And just like other IDEs you need to know where to add breakpoints effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you know but there is a tab inside browser's DevTools called **Network** where you can see all the requests, pause them or see their type.

[image: Network tab inside Devtools]

Comment: Thank you! I'm somewhat familiar with the network tab but always happy to learn more. Can you edit the answer to tell me how I can pause all requests, then step through them one-by-one in your browser of choice? If so, I will mark this as the selected answer, since it does not require any external tools beyond what the browser comes with -- handy when debugging remotely with a non-developer.

Comment: You can pause *all the requests* wit the top-left red button within dev tools or you can get all the requests and then, by dragging the timeline, go step by step for each request.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that what you're looking for can be achieved using Burp Suite. It allows you to intercept client-side requests using its proxy to view and modify them. [here's more detailed explanation](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy/using).

That being said, the devtools are already quite powerful. In the network tab, you can filter requests and simulate a slow connection and you can also block some requests or make a replay among other things. Details are [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) and [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/)